# Consume response from soap web service in Ajax jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I'm calling one of the soap web service and its returning me the soap response, while parsing the response in the ajax, I'm not able to. It says I cannot parse the [Object XMLDocument]. My SOAP method is sending the bytes array to the client.
Now I want to receive it on client side and generate the pdf from it.

My server side code is

```
    @WebMethod(operationName="purchase")
public byte[] getPurchaseDetails(String personId) throws  IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException {

// My business logic
return documentBytes; // Byte array
}
```

### Response which I see in console of browser

```
<ns:getResponse xmlns:ns="http://cb.nsib.com" xmlns:ax212="http://sax.xml.org/xsd" xmlns:ax27="http://rmi.java/xsd" xmlns:ax28="http://io.java/xsd">
    <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">JVBERi0xLjQKJcOkw7zDtsOfCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGVuZ3RoIDMgMCBSL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhb
    </ns:return>
</ns:getResponse>
```

My Ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
url: webServiceURL, 
type: "POST",
dataType: "xml", 
data: 'personId=yyyy', 
processData: false,
//contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
success: function(data) {
    //console.log(data)
    console.log(typeof data)
    console.log(data)
     var xml = data.toString();
    console.log(typeof xml)
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    console.log(xmlDoc)
    console.log($(xmlDoc).find('ns:return').text());

}, 
error: function() {

}
```

});

### Error thrown

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid XML: [object XMLDocument]
at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.r.parseXML (jquery.min.js:4)
at Object.success ((index):26)
at i (
```

How can I get the value which is there in ns:return tag?

Kindly advice me where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You'll need to escape the `:` in the selector, ie. `ns\\:return`, but ensure that the XML has been parsed correctly before that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that is the response coming from SOAP. So it should be correct.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, exactly it says that invalid XML, but when I see the response in SOAP UI, it is the same response

Comment: Donty send the byte array over XML raw. Base64 encode the byte array transfer then base64 decode to byte and write PDF. You cannot transfer the raw bytes in XML.